# How to update PHP versions with Yum on AWS Linux / CentOS

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, centos, yum

I have a web server with PHP 7.3 installed (And Apache + Wordpress), plus a number of PHP related modules. This server is on AWS Linux.

When the AWS repo makes PHP 7.4 available, what's the best way to upgrade the PHP 7.3 packages to 7.4 and preserve my PHP configs? I'm assuming that `sudo yum upgrade` isn't going to cut it. Will I need to uninstall php73-* and then install php74-*?

By way of showing what I have:

```
yum list installed *php*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Installed Packages
php73.x86_64                       7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-cli.x86_64                   7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-common.x86_64                7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-gd.x86_64                    7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-json.x86_64                  7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-mbstring.x86_64              7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-mysqlnd.x86_64               7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-pdo.x86_64                   7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-process.x86_64               7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php73-xml.x86_64                   7.3.17-1.25.amzn1               @amzn-updates
```

Comment: Its not available for Amazon Linux 1. Can't you upgrade to Amazon Linux 2? AL1 is at the end of its life anyway.

Comment: Fantastic - looks like I'm stuck in place for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install PHP 7.4 along with all related packages (extensions) you can use Remi's repository, it even has a setup wizard that will walk you through the process here https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

But you'll have to uninstall your current php version, what I do in these situations is just run `php -m`, save all the modules I have and know my web app will use and then do a `yum remove php*` to remove all traces but review carefully all the removed packages before accepting as it may remove other packages because of dependencies.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think that's probably the answer I needed. 

From the outset I think it's probably worth cloning the instance I'm using and running that as a test. Looks like REMI might not work well with AWS Linux?

Marked as correct anyhow.

Comment: @anakaine AWS Linux 1 is based on an old core of CentOS so it might be a hit or miss with finding working packages right now, I strongly suggest trying to update to AWS Linux 2 if you can

Comment: PHP 7.4 won't be available in Remi Repo for Centos 6 or Amazon Linux 1, fyi. > https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=3931

Answer (score 1):

In amazon linux,

```
yum install php73
```

yum can install PHP 7.3, but not activate it. While it is available in the system, it is not in the path. To activate it, configure it as the preferred alternative.
use following command:

```
sudo alternatives --config php
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I wound up using the remi report and some instructions found elsewhere that i no longer have the link to.ultimately however, it was best to do a clean install and migrate the apps across. That took no more than 20 minutes.